# NSOperation - wait for completion INCLUDING completion block

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I know I can call `[NSOperation waitUntilFinished]` to wait for an NSOperation, but is there a way to include the completionBlock as part of this wait call? Right now I set a BOOL in the completion block to indicate that the operation is finished including the completion block, but surely there must be a better, built in way to do it...

```
[self.requestOperation setCompletionBlock:^{ self.reallyDone = YES; }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a completion block with `waitUntilFinished`. Just put it on the next line after the call to `waitUntilFinished`. That next line won't be reached until the operation completes achieving precisely the same functionality as a completion block.

You only need to use completion blocks when you're doing something asynchronously, but if you're invoking the operation synchronously, that obviates the need for completion block.

Comment: That worked. It required a bit of code refactor but in the end seems to be working great.